# Configuring Connection from Sharepoint List Filter Web Part to List View Web Part

Tags: web-part, filter, configuration, connection

For some reason I can't get a selectable connection to pass the filter values to the list view web part.  I select the web part to pass the filter values to, but then the Connection Box comes up empty - there's no default connection type - or any connection type - to select and configure.  The filter correctly pulls selectable values from the source list.  This is Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise.

[image: Connection Dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've ran into this problem 3 hours before me going by the time of your post.

Apparently one of the issues is that in IE11 you have to turn on compatibility mode. Once I did that it worked, and then I had to select "Get filter values" rather than parameters in order to get the list of filter options.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect - thank you! That was the problem.  Microsoft tried to tell me it was a "user issue"...who would have thought there would be compatibility settings issues between IE 11 and Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Or if using Edge then switch to IE.